# python: TypeError: %c requires int or char

Tags: python, string-formatting

...but "%c" is not in my script, at all.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build_SoS.py", line 88, in <module>
    if int(locID) == int(2501): print " 20% complete with year %s" % str(yr)
TypeError: %c requires int or char
```

Earlier I was getting "unsigned byte integer is greater than maximum," but not every single time, and not this time. Not sure what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have "%c", but you do have "% c".

Inside your format string, that is, the left hand side of the `%` operator, you need to escape the `%` character (appearing in "20%") using another `%` character.

```
print " 20%% complete with year %s" % str(yr)
```

Comment: Or, use format:  `print " 20% complete with year {1}".format(yr)`

Comment: I think you mean ```print " 20% complete with year {0}".format(yr)```